# Find the simple continued fractions for both $\pm \frac{39}{25}$...

Tags: number-theory, continued-fractions

Find the simple continued fractions for both $\pm \frac{39}{25}$?

- So far for $\frac{39}{25}$ I have:

$39 = 1 \times 25 + 14  $

$ 25 = 1\times 14 + 11 $

$14  = 1 \times 11 + 3$

$11 = 3 \times 3 + 2$

$3  = 1 \times 2 + 1$

$2 = 2 \times 1 + 0$

Giving us [1 ; 1, 1, 3, 1,  2 ]

- Then for $ - \frac{39}{25}$ I have:

$ -39 = 1 \times -25 - 14   $

$ - 25 = 1 \times -14 -11 $

$ -14 = 1 \times -11 -3 $

$ -11 = 3 \times -3 -2$

$-3 = 1 \times - 2 - 1 $

$-2 =  2 \times -1 + 0 $

Giving us [1; 1,1,3,1,2]

-I think I have this problem figured out but could someone please confirm or suggest changes. Help is very much appreciated!

Comment: For the negative fraction $-\frac{39}{25}$ would you not first have to add, then subtract $\frac{50}{25}$ to put it in the form $-2+\frac{11}{25}$.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that for $-\frac{39}{25}$ you should first rewrite it as $-2+\frac{11}{25}$. Then

$11=0\times25+11$

$25=2\times11+3$

$11=3\times3+2$

$3=1\times2+1$

$2=2\times1+0$

This gives $-\frac{39}{25}=[-2+0;2,3,1,2]=[-2;2,3,1,2]$

Note that recently there has developed a way of representing negative continued fractions in the form

\begin{equation}
x=a_0-\frac{1}{a_1-\frac{1}{a_2-\frac{1}{\ddots}}}
\end{equation}

In this form one takes the ceiling of each improper fraction.

See the thesis of [Alex Eustis](https://www.math.hmc.edu/seniorthesis/archives/2006/aeustis/aeustis-2006-thesis.pdf).

This approach to negative continued fractions is new to me but if I understand it correctly, then

\begin{equation}
-\frac{39}{25}=-1-\frac{1}{2-\frac{1}{5-\frac{1}{3}}}=[1;2,5,3]_-
\end{equation}